# pandas - cumprod when prior index is in denominator and numerator

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas `Series` (`DivFactor`) I would like to calculate using cumprod. It depends upon two other given series: `AdjClose` and `Div`.

Here's my current loop:

```
DivFactor[0] = 1
for t in range(1, periods):
    DivFactor[t] = DivFactor[t-1] - (Div[t-1] * DivFactor[t-1]) /
                                     (AdjClose[t] / DivFactor[t-1] + Div[t-1]))
```

The issue is that the formula seems to be hard to express in terms of a cumulative product.

Is there a way to recast DivFactor so that I can use pandas cumprod (or another cumulative function) and avoid using a Python loop?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a good way just by looking at it. I suspect a short Cython function (http://cython.org) might be the best way to speed this up.